# ExtJS: Why my view is not showing when use xtype?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

I'm having troubles with a simple app made with ExtJS 6.2.0 without using sencha cmd. The thing is, I can´t show a simple Window after simulating a login.

> My app.js:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
  enabled: true
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
  Ext.application({
    name: 'AdeaProjects',

    requires: [
        'AdeaProjects.view.login.Login'
    ],

    views: [
        'AdeaProjects.view.main.Main'
    ],

    launch: function() {
      Ext.setGlyphFontFamily('FontAwesome');
      Ext.create('AdeaProjects.view.login.Login').show();
    }
  });
});
```

> The login view - Login.js

```
Ext.define('AdeaProjects.view.login.Login', {
  extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
  xtype: 'login',

  requires: [
    'AdeaProjects.view.login.LoginController',
    'Ext.form.Panel'
  ],

  controller: 'login',
  bodyPadding: 10,
  title: 'Inicio de Sesión',
  closable: false,
  autoShow: true,
  draggable: false,
  resizable: false,

  items: {
    xtype: 'form',
    reference: 'form',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'textfield',
      name: 'username',
      fieldLabel: 'Nombre Usuario',
      allowBlank: false
    }, {
      xtype: 'textfield',
      name: 'password',
      inputType: 'password',
      fieldLabel: 'Contraseña',
      allowBlank: false
    }, {
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      hideEmptyLabel: false,
      value: 'Ingrese una contraseña válida.'
    }],
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Login',
      formBind: true,
      glyph: 0xf090,
      listeners: {
        click: 'onLoginClick'
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

The controller - LoginController.js

```
Ext.define('AdeaProjects.view.login.LoginController', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
  alias: 'controller.login',

  onLoginClick: function() {
    localStorage.setItem("UserLoggedIn", true);
    this.getView().destroy();

    Ext.create({
      xtype: 'app-main'
    });
  }

});
```

> And finally the view that I want to show - Main.js

```
Ext.define('AdeaProjects.view.main.Main', {
  extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
  alias: 'widget.app-main',

  requires: [
    'AdeaProjects.view.main.MainController',
    'AdeaProjects.view.main.MainModel'
  ],

  controller: 'main',

  viewModel: {
    type: 'main'
  },

  resizable: false,
  layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 4
  },

  initComponent: function() {
    var group = '';
    this.callParent();
  },

  defaultType: 'button',
  defaults: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    cls: 'btn',
    handler: 'onClickNumber'
  },

  header: {
    items: [{
      xtype: 'displayfield',
      colspan: 4,
      width: 200,
      cls: 'display',
      bind: {
        value: '{display}'
      },
      height: 60,
      padding: 0

    }]
  },
  items: [//more stuff]
});
```

I've tried using alias or xtype but i can´t show the window.
However if i change the following:

```
Ext.create({
  xtype: 'app-main'
});
```

with:

```
Ext.create('AdeaProjects.view.main.Main').show();
```

It works perfectly, but i need to know why I can´t use the lazy loading with the xtype.

Can you help me please? What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: Ext.create({  xtype: 'app-main'}) just creates the window, the same as Ext.create('AdeaProjects.view.main.Main') does. You still need to call show() on the resultant window, regardless of how you create it. Or you can specify autoShow:true in app-main's config.

Comment: As @zeke says above, you are just creating a window with the `Ext.create`, you still need to call the `.show()` method in order to show the window in your application.

Comment: @zeke thank you, it works when i added  autoShow: true.

Comment: @qmat yeah i only need that simple line, than you!